# Assumptions for variables in the ARDL model

Tags: time-series, assumptions, ardl

I am currently working on an ARDL model:
$$
e_t = \sum(e_t) + \sum(GDP_t) + \sum(t_t) + \epsilon_t
$$
where $e$ is electricity demand, and $t$ is degree.

Can someone outline the assumptions that the variables must satify in the ARDL model and tests for cheching these assumptions?

I know that in this model the variables could be $I(0)$ or $I(1)$ but not $I(2)$.

What are the other assumptions and corresponding tests for the variables?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ARDL need no pretesting of order of integration of the variables, and that it is applicable for a mixture of I(0) and I(1) variables with no variable being I(2). But, it requires that the dependent variable should be I(1).

Comment: In the above, I just want to make a couple of corrections. the dependent variable does not need to be I(1). Also, the order of the LHS and RHS just has  to be the same.